# jQuery how to evaluate variable

Tags: jquery, select

I have a select, and need to select option based on model, I found if I directly select option by passing string, it works, but if I use a variable which is a string, then select options by that variable, it won't work.

Here is passing directly by string, which works

```
$(@el).find('.fields>option:contains("cheese")').prop('selected', true)
```

this one use variable, it won't work

```
value = 'cheese'
$(@el).find('.fields>option:contains(value)').prop('selected', true)
```

How can I do `eval()` a variable in jQuery? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `value` is a variable , you need to use `+` to concatenate it with other string:

```
$(@el).find('.fields>option:contains(' + value + ')').prop('selected', true)
```